# Error in Selenium while running androidwebdriver

Tags: selenium, automation

I run the  Sample Selenium code from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver on my htc sensation android device. But while Running it as Android JUnit test from ecclipse, i get this stack trace. Unable to understand it. I am new to Selenium, so any help or suggestion would help me most.
Thanks

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Could not find element with name: q
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'armv7l', os.version: '2.6.35.13-g2299e28', java.version: '0'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidWebDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidWebElement.lookupElement(AndroidWebElement.java:341)
at org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidWebElement.access$1(AndroidWebElement.java:330)
at org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidWebElement$FindByImpl.findElementByName(AndroidWebElement.java:295)
at org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidWebDriver$AndroidFindBy.findElementByName(AndroidWebDriver.java:457)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:286)
at org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidWebDriver.findElement(AndroidWebDriver.java:393)
at simple.app.test.SimpleGoogleTest.testGoogleWorks(SimpleGoogleTest.java:32)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)